# Jasmine/Karma: TypeError: this.role.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am working on writing a test case for one of the pages in an application our team is working on. But I have run into an error in one the test case, I am not finding a way to get past. My Spec file is

```
import { UserApiService } from 'src/app/services/api/user-apiservice';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../services/shared/authentication.service';

import { MainViewComponent } from './mainview.component';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('MainViewComponent', () => {
  let component: MainViewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainViewComponent>;
  let mockTlsApiService, mockMatDialog, mockAuthenticationService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockAuthenticationService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getUserData','getDateData']);
    mockAuthenticationService.getUserRole = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(['admin']));
    mockAuthenticationService.getUserRole.toLowerCase = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(['admin']));
    mockAuthenticationService.getUserFullName = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of([]));

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MainViewComponent ],
      providers: [
        {provide: UserApiService, useValue: mockTlsApiService},
        {provide: MatDialog, useValue: mockMatDialog},
        {provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: mockAuthenticationService},
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainViewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The Code that it is testing when I get the error is this

```
  constructor(    
    private repoService: UserApiService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
  ) {
   
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
    switch (property) {
       case 'origDate': return new Date(item.origDate);
       default: return item[property];
    }
  };
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getQueues();

    this.getData();

    this.toolOrderNoFilterFunc(); this.toolNoFilterFunc(); this.eclFilterFunc(); this.abbrFilterFunc(); this.seriesFilterFunc(); this.nameFilterFunc(); this.toolTypeFilterFunc();
    this.toolChangeFilterFunc(); this.ccnDesFilterFunc(); this.ccnFabFilterFunc(); this.revFilterFunc();
  }
. . .
  getQueues(){
    this.role=this.authenticationService.getUserRole();
    this.allQueues = ['ME1', 'ME2', 'Est', 'Safe', 'TFab', 'Fin', 'Acct', 'Shop Stat','Rel']
    this.userFullName = this.authenticationService.getUserFullName();
    //is it Tfab or Tool???
    if(this.role.toLowerCase().search("admin") != -1 ){
        this.arrayQueues = ['ME1', 'ME2', 'Est', 'Safe', 'TFab', 'Fin', 'Acct', 'Shop Stat','Rel']
        //this.arrayQueues = ['TFab', 'Fin', 'ME1']
    } else {
      if(this.role.toLowerCase().search("me or designer") != -1 ){
          this.arrayQueues.push('ME1')
          this.arrayQueues.push('ME2')
      }
      if(this.role.toLowerCase().search("estimating") != -1 ){
        this.arrayQueues.push('Est')
      }
      if(this.role.toLowerCase().search("saftey") != -1 ){
        this.arrayQueues.push('Safe')  //is it SAF or Safe???
      }
      if(this.role.toLowerCase().search("tool fab") != -1 ){
        //is it Tfab or Tool???
        this.arrayQueues.push('TFab') 
      }
      if(this.role.toLowerCase().search("finance") != -1 ){
        this.arrayQueues.push('Fin')
      }
      if(this.role.toLowerCase().search("accountability") != -1 ){
        this.arrayQueues.push('Acct')
      }
      if(this.role.toLowerCase().search("read only") != -1 ){
        this.arrayQueues = this.allQueues
      }
    }

    this.isempty = false;
    // console.log(this.arrayQueues)
  }
```

When the test reaches the first this.role.toLowerCase(), I am getting the error that is the title of this post.

I have tried to create a mock for role and a mock for toLowerCase, but those wind up with more errors. I have also tried to use spyOn.

How can I get this error message fixed?

Comment: Does `this.authenticationService.getUserRole()` always return a `string` 100% of the time?  Or does it occasionally return something like `null` or `undefined`?  If so then you have to do something to handle these cases, because you will get this error if calling `null.toLowerCase()`

Comment: `wind up with more errors` ??? what were those errors. You should always mock a service as a part of unit testing.  If you can share those errors, we can help you fix that

Comment: For the time being, I am currently working on other components in the application. I will probably get back to this later today. To Shashank's comment, I believe and maybe I am wrong, the part where I am creating mockAuthenticationService was a mock of the service.  It is possible I may have to mock it in a different way for this component, but for all of the other components in this application that way of mocking has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I changed how I was mocking the Authentication service from

```
mockAuthenticationService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getUserData','getDateData']);
mockAuthenticationService.getUserRole = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(['admin']));
mockAuthenticationService.getUserRole.toLowerCase = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(['admin']));
mockAuthenticationService.getUserFullName = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of([]));
```

to this

```
export class mockAuthentication{
  getUserRole(){
    return "admin";
  };
  getUserFullName(){
    return "Test User";
  }
};
```

and Update the provide statement from

```
{provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: mockAuthenticationService},
```

to this

```
{provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: mockAuthentication},
```

and my test is now passing. What through me for a loop was that the first method of mocking the service has worked in multiple other components in the same application.